# Does the complex plane exist purely for commodity?

Tags: complex-analysis, neural-networks

Let $F=\{f\}_i$ be the set of functions $f_i: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, and $G=\{g\}_i$ be the set of functions $g_i: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. As far as I understand, the only difference between $g_i$ and $f_i$ is differentiability, since being complex differentiable is much harder than differentiability in the 2D plane. However, as long as $f_i$ respects the Cauchy-Riemnan equations, then $f_i$ can be mapped onto the complex plane and thus being complex differentiable. Therefore, if we let $H$ be the set of mapped complex functions, such that $h_i(Re(z),Im(z))=\begin{pmatrix}{Re(f_i(z)) \\ Im(f_i(z))}\end{pmatrix}$, then $H\subset G$. If this is true, then there is no loss of information or dynamics from working the complex plane or an R2 plane. Therefore, is the complex plane a mere comodity? In other words, is it true that there is no function $f_i$ that can't be mapped onto $g_i$?

**Context**

This question came while studying complex valued neural networks (CVNNs). It looks as though the only significant difference in CVNNs with respect to a real valued neural network (RVNN) with input neurons for the real and imaginary parts of the input data, is the activation function and the number of parameters to optimize. Indeed, a CVNN optimizes real and imaginary part to map $z_1\to z_2$, while RNN has 4 parameters to optimize for the same problem giving rise to redundancy, but it could be overcome via contraints. As for the activation function, I got stuck in the above question.

Comment: But doesn’t $\Bbb R^2$ also exist just for commodity, because I may as well talk about $\Bbb R$ and pairs of its elements? In fact, $\Bbb R$ exists just for commodity since I could talk about Cauchy sequences of rationals. And so on

Comment: Perhaps you can. But I always saw the complex plane as something completely new and separate from R2, with exotic behaviours. But maybe that's not quite true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no difference between an holomorphic function defined on the whole complex plane and a pair of real-valued $C^2$ functions defined on ${\bf R}^2$ satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

EDIT: a function from ${\bf C}$ to ${\bf C}$ is [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) if it is complex differentiable, in the sense that ${f(z+h)-f(z) \over h}$ has a limit as $h$ goes to $0$ in ${\bf C}$.

Comment: I noticed you said " holomorphic function". Since I'm not from a mathematics background, can I ask you to expand a bit more? In other words, what I asked in the main question is: is there any function in C that can't be reproduced in R2?

Comment: There are plenty of differentiable functions that do not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, for example $f(x,y) = 2x$. This function corresponds to the function from ${\bf C}$ to ${\bf C}$ given by $f(z) = z+\overline{z}$.

Comment: Hmm, indeed, but isn't $f(z)$ complex differentiable?

Comment: No, the function $f(z) = z+\bar{z}$ is not complex differentiable.

Comment: While reading your answer and comments, another question came up. Can I ask you to take a look? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4655638/is-there-any-function-in-the-complex-plane-thats-cant-be-reproduced-in-r2