# Is there any function in the complex plane that's can't be reproduced in R2?

Tags: complex-analysis

This question comes as a follow-up from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4655593/520539). In that question, I focused on complex differentiable functions. As this came up in the context of complex valued neural networks, I'm interested in non-linear transformations in the complex plane that do not need to be complex differentiable but that can't be replicated in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do these functions exist?

Comment: There are no such transformations.

Comment: There is a bijective mapping between the elements of $C$ and $R^2$, so every function can be transformed. It might lose properties like differentiability but it will still be a function.

Answer (score 3):

To any function $f:{\bf C} \rightarrow {\bf C}$, you can associate a function $g:{\bf R}^2 \rightarrow {\bf R}^2$  using the formula
$$
g(x,y) = (Re(f(x+iy)), Im(f(x+iy)))
$$
where $Re(z)$ is the real part of the complex number $z$ and $Im(z)$ its imaginary part. Note that $Re(z) = {z+\bar{z} \over 2}$ and $Im(z) = {z-\bar{z} \over 2i}$.